# How do I detect the edge of a scanned baseball card and crop the image to just the card with python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, crop, detection

I'm scanning a bunch of baseball cards in protective sleeves. I'd like to crop just the card or slightly more then the exact edge of the card. I've been using Python for the past few years and would like some guidance how how best to do this. Here is a sample image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3tFG.jpg)

I've reviewed some articles on OpenCV and Pillow but none are similar enough to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you want the blue border or just the inner white border of the card itself?

Comment: No blue border, just the white border that is part of the actual card, the true card edge, not the plastic protection top loader it sits inside. Leave a little space beyond the actual baseball card edge so the quality of the edge is visible but exclude everything else beyond towards the outer edge of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not said whether you want to include the blue border or just the card inside the blue border.  Here is one way to do the latter in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input image
img = cv2.imread('baseball_card.jpg')

# threshold on white
lower = (210,210,210)
upper = (235,235,235)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# apply morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7,7))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# get rotated rectangle
rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(big_contour)
(center), (width,height), angle = rotrect
box = cv2.boxPoints(rotrect)
boxpts = np.intp(box)

# draw rotated rectangle on copy of image
rotrect_img = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(rotrect_img,[boxpts],0,(0,0,255),2)

# create mask
mask = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask,[boxpts],0,(255,255,255),-1)

# apply mask to input
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)


# ADDITION:
# get bounding box of rotated rectangle box
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(boxpts)

# crop image to bounding box
crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# save images
cv2.imwrite('baseball_card_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('baseball_card_morph.jpg', morph)
cv2.imwrite('baseball_card_rot_rect.jpg', rotrect_img)
cv2.imwrite('baseball_card_mask.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('baseball_card_result.jpg', result)
cv2.imwrite('baseball_card_crop.jpg', crop)

# show results
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('rotated rectangle', rotrect_img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('crop', crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology Cleaned Image:

[image]

Rotated Rectangle Image:

[image]

Mask Image:

[image]

Result Image:

[image]

Cropped Image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Very exciting, I will give this a try. Yes, the goal is to capture the card including its white edge plus a little beyond the edge so the quality of the card edge is visible but excludes everything else.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when running the python code provided:
OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1726: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ! _src.empty() in function 'cv::inRange'
  File "D:\Users\tom\OneDrive\Dev\playground\image processing\solution.py", line 10, in <module>
    thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1726: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ! _src.empty() in function 'cv::inRange'

Comment: There is no input image.  Check your path to your input image. If the image is not in your current working directory, then put the full path to the image.  Check the shape of the input image to verify your have a valid image. Check the spelling of the input name and suffix. Please try to do some debugging on your own. Just simple things like mentioned here. Also search Google for your error message. It can often tell you what the issue is.

Comment: Note a simpler approach to my answer would be to just get the contour as above and then get the bounding box of the contour. The rotated rectangle, etc might not be needed. Use the bounding box of the contour to crop the image.